# Android: opening activity in a view

Tags: android

I am a newbie to android, I want an activity to be shown in a view from an intent, so how can I achieve that? Basically it means an activity that does not fill up the whole screen, instead any other activities can run under that "floating" activity.

Comment: read about fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [`Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

They are like mini activities or independent component of your app that can be a part of multiple activities.

Comment: But can I open an activity over any other applications like a popup window using fragments? Or are there any better ways for achieving so?

Comment: u can use dialogFragment but not sure what are u asking

Comment: Actually if I can add a fragment using a WindowManager then the problem can basically be solved. Cause as far as I understand you can start an activity within a fragment right?